# How to serialize from XML to C#.net when child node are same name

Tags: c#, xml

This is the file structure:

```
<BODY>
    <IMPORTDATA>
            <REQUESTDATA>
                <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
                    <VOUCHER REMOTEID="abcd1" VCHKEY="0000a582:000000e0" VCHTYPE="Payment" ACTION="Create" OBJVIEW="Accounting Voucher View">
                        <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                            <LEDGERNAME>Bank Charges</LEDGERNAME>
                            <AMOUNT>-575.00</AMOUNT>
                        </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                        <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                            <LEDGERNAME>Standard Chartered Bank Ltd-01-5547520-01</LEDGERNAME>
                            <AMOUNT>575.00</AMOUNT>
                        </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                    </VOUCHER>
                </TALLYMESSAGE>
            </REQUESTDATA>
        </IMPORTDATA>
    </BODY>
```

Here there are two `ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST`'s. How do I find the value of `LEDGERNAME` of these two `ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST`'s?
I detect the node this way

```
XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/ENVELOPE/BODY/IMPORTDATA/REQUESTDATA/TALLYMESSAGE/VOUCHER")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use little-bid more friendly API for working with xml - [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693062.aspx)

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(PathToXmlFile);

var ledgerNames = doc.Root
                     .Descendants("ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST")
                     .Elements("LEDGERNAME")
                     .Select(element => element.Value);

foreach (var name in ledgerNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

`Descendants` will return all xml elements with given name existed in xml file on any level. [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx)

So basically you can use `Descendants` straight for `LEDGERNAME` elements and omit `Root` too.

```
var ledgerNames = doc.Descendants("LEDGERNAME")
                     .Select(element => element.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the XML (mark all and click ctrl + c). In visual studio go to

> Edit > Past Special > Past XML As Classes

This will create the XML structure as C# classes.
`ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST` will be presented as an array.